# Why my Form shows good alone, but mess-up when put into the whole page?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form with its HTML and CSS, the form shows good without combining with other elements. But when I try to put it into my whole page(the left column of the content area), the form looks just 'normal', not as good as before.

Below is the HTML and CSS for the whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bookstore</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="header">   
 <!--   <img src=" " class="logo">   -->
    <h1 class="logo_text">Book store</h1>

    <form action="http://www.base-domain.com/" method="post" class="login_form">     

      <div class="login_form_input_container">

        <label for="email" class="login_form_label">Email</label>

        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="login_form_input">
      </div>

      <div class="login_form_input_container">  

        <label for="password" class="login_form_label">Password</label>

        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="login_form_input">

      </div>

      <a href="http://www.base-domain.com/forgot_password/" 

class="forgot_password_link">Forgot password?</a>

      <input type="submit" id="login_submit" name="login_submit" value="Log In" 

class="login_form_submit">

    </form>

  </div><!-- end .header -->


  <div class="nav">

    <ul class="nav_links">    

      <li class="nav_link_container"><a href="" class="nav_link">link one</a></li>

      <li class="nav_link_container"><a href="" class="nav_link">link one</a></li>

      <li class="nav_link_container"><a href="" class="nav_link">link one</a></li>

      <li class="nav_link_container"><a href="" class="nav_link">link one</a></li>

      <li class="nav_link_container"><a href="" class="nav_link">link one</a></li>

    </ul>

  </div><!-- end .nav -->


<!-- begin .content, which contains .sidebar and .main columns -->
  <div class="content">

    <div class="sidebar">

      <div id="search_form_wrapper">

        <form name="search" action="/" method="post" class="search_form">

        <fieldset><legend>I'm looking for...</legend>

        <div>
        <label class="search_form_label" for="keywords">Key Words</label>
        </div>

        <div>
        <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Keywords"/>
        </div>

        <div>
        <label class="search_form_label" for="county">County</label>
        </div>

        <div>
        <input type="text" name="county" placeholder="County"/>
        </div>

        <div class="search_button_group"> 
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search jobs"/>

          <div class="advanced_search_link"><a href="" class="advanced_search_link">Advanced 

Search</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        </fieldset> 

        </form>

      </div><!-- end .search_form_wrapper -->

    </div><!-- end .sidebar -->


    <div class="main">

      <h2 class="main_h2">Book stroe</h2>

      <p class="main_p1">Book stroe</p>

      <img src="" alt="staff banner" width="81%" height="206" class="main_banner">

      <p class="main_p2">Book stroe.</p>

      <h3>Book stroe</h3>

  <p>Book stroe.</p>

    </div><!-- end .main -->

  </div> <!-- end .content -->


  <div class="footer">

    <ul class="footer_menu">

      <li><a href="">Site Map</a></li>

      <li><a href="/>Site Map</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Site Map</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Site Map</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Discrimination</a></li>

    </ul>

    <p class="copyright"><strong>Copyright &copy; </p>

  </div><!-- end .footer -->

</div><!-- end .container -->

</body>
</html>
```

And the css file is here:

```
a, body, div, form, html, img, label, li, ul {

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

}

body {

    font-size: 16px;

    font-family: Tahoma, "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;

    background: url("../images/bg.gif") repeat-x left top;

}

.container {

    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 1250px;

}

.header {



    overflow: hidden;

}

.logo {

    display: block;

    float: left;

}

.logo_text {

    float: left;

    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);

    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-weight: bold;

    width: 956px;
}


.login_form {

    overflow: hidden;

}

.login_form_input_container {

    margin: 5px;

    overflow: hidden;

}

.login_form_label {

    display: block;

    float: left;

    font-size: 1.125em;

    font-weight: bold;

    margin-top: 4px;

    width: 80px;

}

.login_form_input {

    display: block;

    float: right;

    width: 185px;

}

.forgot_password_link {

    color: #2A667C;

    display: inline-block;

    /*display: inline; */

    margin: 10px 0 0 5px;



    /*zoom: 1;  */

}

.login_form_submit {

    background: #2A667C;

    border-radius: 8px;

    color: #FFF;

    cursor: pointer;

    display: block;

    float: right;

    font-size: 1.125em;

    font-weight: bold;

    margin-right: 5px;

    padding: 4px 8px;

}

.login_form_submit:hover {

    background: #98BF21;

}

.nav {

    background: #98BF21;

    text-align: center;

    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

}

.nav_links {

    list-style: none;

    margin: 0 auto;

    overflow: hidden;

    width: 900px;

}

.nav_link_container {

    float: left;

    width: 180px;

}

.nav_link {

    color: #FFF;

    display: block;

    font-size: 1.25em;

    font-weight: bold;

    padding: 10px;

    text-align: center;

    text-decoration: none;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    width: 160px;

}

.nav_link:hover {

    background: #2A667C;

}


/** Content Div **/
.content {

    clear: both; /* clear #nav ul li's following elements */

    width: 100%; /* set the width of #content to 100% */

    overflow: hidden; /* make it stretch to contain the floated elements */

    margin-top: 1.5em;

}

.sidebar {

    float: left;

    width: 30%;

    margin-right: 5%;

}

/* search form */
.search_form_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.search_form_wrapper legend {
    color:#0481b1;
    font-size:21px;
    padding:0 10px;
    background:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.search_form_wrapper fieldset {
    border-radius:4px;
    background: #fff; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#f9fdff)); /
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
    padding:20px;
    border-color:rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.4);
}

.search_form_wrapper input {
    color: #373737;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.search_form_wrapper input[type="text"] {
    padding: 8px 6px;
    height: 22px;
    width:280px;
}

.search_form_wrapper input[type="text"]:focus {
    background:#f5fcfe;
    text-indent: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #373737;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: width, background;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-transition-property: width, background;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -o-transition-property: width, background;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
    width: 380px;

    border-color:#ccc;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
    opacity:0.6;
}

.search_form_wrapper input[type="submit"]{
    background: #222;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 22px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.search_form_label {
    display: block;
    width: 8em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #2A9FAA; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin: 7px 0;
}

.search_button_group {
    float: left;
}

.advanced_search_link {
    color: #2A667C;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 8px;
    color: rgb(49, 90, 170);
    font-size: 18px;
}

a.advanced_search_link:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: #2A00FF;
}
/* search form ends */


.main 
{
    float: left;
    width: 812.5px;
    overflow: hidden; /* make it stretch to contain the floated elements */ 
}

.main-h2 
{

    font-size: 280%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.main_banner {
    width: 65%;

}


.main_p1
{

    font-size: 135%;
    margin-left: 0.3em;

}

.main_p2
{

    font-size: 130%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
}   


/** Footer Div **/
.footer 
{
    clear: left; /* starts the footer below the floated content */
    overflow: hidden; /* make it stretch to contain the floated elements */
    width: 100%;      /* fix float containment fail */
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-top: 10px solid #98BF21;
    background-color:#1183DA;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

ul.footer_menu 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both; /* starts the nav below the floated header */
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;

    color: #FFF; 
}

ul.footer_menu li 
{
    display:inline-block;
} 

ul.footer_menu li a:link, ul.footer_menu li a:visited 
{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    /* text-transform:uppercase;*/
}
ul.footer_menu li a:hover, ul.footer_menu li a:active 
{
    background-color:#98BF21;
}


.copyright 
{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

}

strong
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you show the code above in the browser, you could see the form on the left column doesn't look very nice.

But in this single file below, if you run it in the browser, you'll find the form looks great:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Register form with HTML5 using placeholder and CSS3</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width:450px;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    #wrapper legend {
        color:#0481b1;
        font-size:21px;
        padding:0 10px;
        background:#fff;
        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
        padding:5px 10px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    #wrapper fieldset {
        border-radius:4px;
        background: #fff; 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#f9fdff)); /
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
        padding:20px;
        border-color:rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.4);
    }
    #wrapper input {
        color: #373737;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        color: #aaa;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        margin-bottom:15px;

        -moz-border-radius:4px;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:4px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
    #wrapper input[type="text"] {
        padding: 8px 6px;
        height: 22px;
        width:280px;
    }
    #wrapper input[type="text"]:focus {
        background:#f5fcfe;
        text-indent: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        color: #373737;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
        -webkit-transition-property: width, background;
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
        -moz-transition-property: width, background;
        -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
        -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
        -o-transition-property: width, background;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
        width: 380px;

        border-color:#ccc;
        box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
        opacity:0.6;
    }
    #wrapper input[type="submit"]{
        background: #222;
        border: none;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color: #eee;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 10px 0;
        padding: 5px 22px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius:4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }



.search_form_label {
    display: block;
    width: 8em;
    text-align: left;
    color: #2A9FAA; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin: 7px 0;
}

.search_button_group {
    float: left;
}
.advanced_search_link {
        color: #2A667C;

    display: inline-block;

    /*display: inline; */
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 8px;
color: rgb(49, 90, 170);
font-size: 18px;

}

a.advanced_search_link:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: #2A00FF;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form name="search" action="/" method="post" class="search_form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>I'm looking for...</legend>
                <div>
                        <label class="search_form_label" for="keywords">Key 

Words</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Keywords"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <label class="search_form_label" for="county">County</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="county" placeholder="County"/>
                </div>

                <div class="search_button_group"> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search jobs"/>
                                <div 

class="advanced_search_link">
                                      <a href="" 

class="advanced_search_link">Advanced Search</a>
                      </div>
                      </div>
            </fieldset>    
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the form look great in the whole page as well? Can anyone help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You write `<link rel="styleshtte" href="styles.css">`

You should write `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` and check if this is the correct path for styles.css.

Do you have the `styles.css` file in the same folder as your html form?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Yes, the styles.css file is in the same folder. Everything works good in the browser except the form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle, this might be what you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/uFFXX/

```
  #wrapper {
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
}
#wrapper legend {
    color:#0481b1;
    font-size:21px;
    padding:0 10px;
    background:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
    padding:5px 10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#wrapper fieldset {
    border-radius:4px;
    background: #fff; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fff), to(#f9fdff)); /
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #f9fdff);
    padding:20px;
    border-color:rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.4);
}
#wrapper input {
    color: #373737;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom:15px;

    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
#wrapper input[type="text"] {
    padding: 8px 6px;
    height: 22px;
    width:280px;
}
#wrapper input[type="text"]:focus {
    background:#f5fcfe;
    text-indent: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #373737;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-property: width, background;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-transition-property: width, background;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -o-transition-property: width, background;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
    width: 380px;

    border-color:#ccc;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(4, 129, 177, 0.5);
    opacity:0.6;
}
#wrapper input[type="submit"]{
    background: #222;
    border: none;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 22px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Have just taken some of your CSS from the form page and put it in your style sheet and changed in your full page. Hope this is what you're looking for.